# Can I use dependency injection in the definition of a custom validation attribute?

Tags: c#, validation, unity-container, prism

I'm using Prism and Unity for the application, and I have a custom validation attribute that I want to validate the field against a table in the database.  I would like to inject the Repository service into the validator, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

I have used the dependency attribute on a property, but that didn't work. The property remained null.

I tried constructor injection, but it conflicts with the attribute signature.

Is this possible?  If not, what is another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get stuff injected into classes that you have the container create for you.

That means, if you create your validator through `Resolve` or (preferred) have it injected into the class that uses it, constructor injection in the validator itself will work fine. If you create the validator with `new` or `Activator.CreateInstance`, there won't be any injection.

Comment: Since it is a validation attribute, I don't have access to the point it is created.  So that means I can't inject into the validation attribute.  Instead, I'm setting a static public property on the validator class to get the repository service into it.